# RxJava Return Subscribed value in a function

Tags: operators, rx-java

For some reason, i sometimes want to use RxOperators instead of the normal java-way of transforming data structures, because its cleaner and cleaner. For example:

```
Observable.from(listOfStrings)
.filter(string -> string.getNumber() >5)
.toList()
```

Is there any way of waiting for the result of the observable and return in in a function: This would do (but it doesn't work):

```
private String getFilteredString(String string){
   Observable.from(listOfStrings)
       .filter(string -> string.getNumber() >5)
       .toList()
       .subscribe(finalStirng -> {
       return finalString;
       })
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can transform any `Observable` to a synchronous one using `.toBlocking()`:

```
private List<String> getFilteredString(List<String> strings) {
  return Observable.from(strings)
      .filter(string -> string.length() > 5)
      .toList()
      .toBlocking()
      .single();
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Although the code above is perfectly valid and will work as expected, this isn't how `RxJava` is supposed to be used. If your only goal is to transform a collection, there are better ways to do it:

- Java 8 has a [`Stream` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)
- [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) has its own [collections API](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/FunctionalExplained)
- Apache has a [`commons-collections`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/index.html) library

Comment: yes i agree but, in my case, i disagree :p First because i'm on android, so i dont have java8. Another reason, i have to do that transformations in the normal-java way anyway, so for me rxOperators are cleaner. You see my point?

Comment: Android doesn't (yet) have Stream, and Guava contains a *massive* number of method references (bad for Android's 65k dex limit).  RxJava is popular in Android apps and using it in place of Stream etc is quite reasonable I feel.

Comment: I am already using rx in other places in my android app. Integrating any other library for this purposes has a cost as @Tom mentioned. This answer is the best solution for me and I think for a lot other andoird devs.

Answer (score 3):

There is an instance method on `rx.Observable` called `x()` ([link](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/e16300760bcbb6847c20dc1674bee8ba06793bc8/src/main/java/rx/Observable.java#L122)) that can be used to covert an observable to another value directly and fluently. The intent of this operator is to build up a repository of conversion functions that can switch an Observable into other kinds of concurrent/asynchronous data structures (such as other kinds of observables) or just simply unwrap the contents of the observable into the contained values. Write the conversion function once and store it away for repeated use.

Method signature:

```java
public <R> R x(Func1<? super OnSubscribe<T>, ? extends R> conversion);
```

Usage for converting a potentially asynchronous observable to a concurrent list:

```java
List<Integer> list = Observable.range(1, 10).x(new Func1<OnSubscribe<Integer>, List<Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public List<Integer> call(OnSubscribe<Integer> onSubscribe) {
        List<Integer> allElements = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        AtomicReference<Throwable> failure = new AtomicReference<Throwable>();
        onSubscribe.call(new Subscriber<Integer>(){
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                latch.countDown();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                failure.set(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Integer t) {
                allElements.add(t);
            }});
        while (true) {
            try {
                latch.await();
                break;
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // continue waiting
            }
        }
        Throwable e = failure.get();
        if (e != null)
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        return allElements;

    }});
System.out.println(list);
```

output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Please note that this operator is currently `@Experimental` and is very likely to be renamed (to "extend"), however experimental functionality in RxJava can be [changed in any release](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#experimental).